# insert statement from 2 different table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i have a childTable and parentTable, and familyTable is my new created table
what i trying to do it to link child and parent table unique ID

my expected result is like table below

**FamilyTable**

```
   -------------
FamilyID | ParentID, ChildID
------------
1       |  1   | 1
2       |  2   | 2
```

but i failed to do it and below is my current database design

** Current Database Design**

**ChildTable**

```
-------------
ChildID | ChildNm
------------
1       |  A
2       |  B
```

**ParentTable**

```
   -------------
ParentID| ParentNm
------------
1       |  A
2       |  B
```

**FamilyTable**

```
   -------------
FamilyID | ParentID, ChildID
------------
1       |  
2       |
```

below is my insert statement

```
INSERT INTO FamilyTable (ParentID,ChildID)
SELECT p.ParentID, c.ChildID
FROM ParentTable p, ChildTable c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM FamilyTable where parentsID=p.parentID and childID=c.childID)
```

my actual result for this query

**FamilyTable**

```
   -------------
FamilyID | ParentID, ChildID
------------
1       |  1  |  1
2       |  2  |  1
3       |  1  |  2
4       |  2  |  2
```

and this is not the result that i want, is that any body can give me some idea??

Comment: Unclear. Consider providing a sqlfiddle together with your desired result set.

Comment: how do you know the relationships between parents and children ?

Comment: basically i need to do a data patching, there are no parents table and family table in original design

Comment: so the requirements is insert a list of parents ID with same ID with child ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you match them up on parentnm / childnm (otherwise you just land up with a cross join giving you every possible combination which is what you currently have)

```
INSERT INTO FamilyTable (ParentID,ChildID)
SELECT p.ParentID, c.ChildID
FROM ParentTable p
INNER JOIN ChildTable c
ON p.ParentN, = c.ChildNm
LEFT OUTER JOIN FamilyTable f
ON f.parentsID = p.parentID AND f.childID=c.childID
WHERE f.parentsID IS NULL
```